# Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 500 I/O error on POST request for https://abcd.com Connection reset;

Tags: java, kubernetes, digital-ocean

i have added proxy protocol true from ingress controller on k8. and suddenly api falling. my cloude provider is Digital Ocean. i have added service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-proxy-protocol: "true" in service and data:
use-forwarded-headers: "true"
compute-full-forwarded-for: "true"
use-proxy-protocol: "true" in config map